# How to read a blasted resistor?

Tags: resistors

I have this table fan which wasn't working one day. So I took it apart and found the resistor near the power supply exploded. The colour bands are completely messed up. Only the top and the bottom ones can be seen.

Is there any way to find what value it is without using an ohmmeter as I don't own one? Maybe by knowing the wattage consumption of the fan or something like that?  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BszlZ.jpg]

Comment: The cheapest ohmmeter I've found on amazon in five seconds costs less than eight dollars. It's also useful to have one at hand, since it sounds like you're going to attempt a repair yourself. Just saying.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please take the Tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour. That looks indeed blasted! Even if you would replace it with the correct value, the problem probably presists somewhere else and will blast your new resistor too.

Comment: No, there isn't - you would either need manufacturer documentation (sadly the days of a schematic sticker inside the housing are long gone) or to recognize the circuit sufficiently by inspection to deduce the role and thus appropriate value.  Unfortunately, for this reason **Repair Questions** are off-topic here unless the asker can provide key documentation or an understanding of the device's circuitry.

Comment: Not only are repair questions off-topic here, but *we don't do well at them* -- find a good repair site, and be sure to include the make & model of your fan.  With luck, someone will already know.

Comment: Even with a meter, it's unlikely that resistor is anywhere close to its original resistance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, its gone, and if it got blasted there is a high probability that the coil is also been changed from the original value.

- Find another resistor that looks similar
- Reverse engineer the circuit and see if there is a value that makes sense
- Find another unit and get the resistor value from that
- Find a schematic from the manufacturer if possible.

The biggest problem is: even if you do replace the resistor, there could be an underlying problem that could explode the new one, so it may not do you any good.